# How to check if window.localStorage contains any values

Tags: javascript, html

How do I check if `window.localStorage` already contains **any** values?

Something like :

```
if(window.localStorage.hasItems()){ 
      // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [length property](https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/#dom-storage-length) of the [storage interface](https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/)

```
if(localStorage.length){
}
```

- [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)
- [Storage.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/length)

Answer (score 1):

The length attribute will help to identify this . Try this in browser console.

```
window.localStorage.length
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `localStorage.length` will return the number of keys stored in local storage.

Local storage should **always** be accessed inside a try/catch block. Otherwise if storage is disabled, full, or unavailable you will receive an error.

```
var n;
try {

  // get the length
  n = window.localStorage.length;

} catch (e) {
  // no banana
}

// nein storage
if(!n) return; 

// storage! do something awesome
```